# Setting JQuery Variable to HTML Element Attribute Substring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to set a variable to equal the text of a substring. Specifically, if a[href] begins with "download.php", I'd like to set the variable "elm" to the value of a[href], after the 19th character.

```
if ("a[href^='download.php']") {
    var elm = $('a[href]'.substring(19));
};
```

I've tried using .text() and .html(), but can't get it working. Can someone point out my errors? Many thanks.

Comment: `"a[href^='download.php']"` is a string which is a truthy value, you are doing something fundamentally wrong here.

Comment: A boolean element needs to be inside of an if statement, not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = $("a[href^='download.php']");
if (a.length) {
  var elm = a.attr("href").substring(19);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need your if statement, since you are passing a string which is a truthy value.

To get the value of `href` atributte use [$.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
var elm = $("a[href^='download.php']").attr('href').substring(19);
```

and if you want to check if exists any element who match with `[href^='download.php']` use

```
var el = $("a[href^='download.php']");
if(el.length) {
    var elm = el.first().attr('href').substring(19);
}
```

Comment: No, if there is no element that matches, it will break the script. since `attr('href')` will be undefined. That is the whole point of check in OP's code.

Comment: Better but again why do you need to create jq object again. You can cache it. I mean a lot like the other answer.